# Is there any shortcut command to compile or is it just clicking the green play button?

Tags: compiling

Yep. That's my question. Huh. I need to fill this when I actually don't need to.

Comment: Don't see green button here.

Comment: You will need to tell us what editor you are talking about: my guess is TeXworks

Comment: you say "I actually don't need to" add text there but you are missing all the relevant information that should be in your question. You are asking about some editor without even saying what editor you are using.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. (Assuming TeXworks.)

As given in the Typeset  menu:

[image: texworks typeset menu]

Answer (score 1):

TeXStudio, which has a green play-like button, is F5 in Linux and Windows